# How do i arranged by reading two text files using bash?

Tags: bash

I have a two text files text

cat A.txt

```
10,1,1,"ABC"
10,1,2,"ABC"
10,1,3,"baba"
10,2,1,"asd"
10,2,2,"dkkd"
```

cat B.txt

```
10,1,2,"S1"
10,2,1,"S2"
10,2,2,"S3"
```

I want contents of file B.txt should appear above the matched from A.txt
Here i need to compare the three numbers which are separated by commas. say (10,1,2) of A.txt and (10,1,2) of B.txt if they found equal then it add to above
How do i get this output and save to another file using bash

```
10,1,1,"ABC"
10,1,2,"S1"
10,1,2,"ABC"
10,1,3,"baba"
10,2,1,"S2"
10,2,1,"asd"
10,2,2,"S3"
10,2,2,"dkkd"
```

Comment: `10,1,2,"S1"
10,1,2,"ABC"` why S1 is in front of ABC? not ABC -> S1

Comment: I have edited my my post @KamilCuk

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just sort the files using the first three fields. Because you prefer lines from `B.txt` in front of `A.txt`, I used `-s, --stable` option to disable last-resort sorting, hoping for `sort` to pick the first line it reads. So by specifying the first file to be `B.txt`, I hope it will places `B.txt` lines in front.

```
sort -s -t, -k1,3 B.txt A.txt
```

will output:

```
10,1,1,"ABC"
10,1,2,"S1"
10,1,2,"ABC"
10,1,3,"baba"
10,2,1,"S2"
10,2,1,"asd"
10,2,2,"S3"
10,2,2,"dkkd"
```